# python3 mysqldb cursor.fetchone

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to find complete documentation for cursor.fetchone and all I can find is:
http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.CursorStoreResultMixIn-class.html#fetchone

my questions are:
what is exactly returned? a normal python array?
what does it return if there no more rows?
what does it do if the connection is dropped? throw an error? have a unique return value?
I am not sure why I can't find real documentation on this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer in order your questions.

> What is exactly returned?

A tuple or a dictionary, depending how you did the connection.

> What does it return if there no more rows?

None

> What does it do if the connection is dropped?

An Exception is raised. If it's due to a timeout, for instance, it will be a `MySQLdb.OperationalError`.

> I am not sure why I can't find real documentation on this

Try here: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/